# Custom middleware in redux-toolkit is making API endpoint return nothing

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I've a login component which calls userLogin api endpoint when a user logs in, I've configured a toast which then alerts about the login and the user is taken to the home page. For persisting the login state, I've used a middleware wherein the login information is stored in the localstorage.

This is the redux store

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import Apiservice from "./service/apiService";
import userReducer from "./slices/userSlice";
import postReducer from "./slices/postSlice";

const authMiddleware = (store) => (next) => (action) => {
  if (Apiservice.endpoints.userLogin.matchFulfilled(action)) {
    localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(action.payload));
  }
  return next(action);
};

const postsMiddleware = (store) => (next) => (action) => {
  if (Apiservice.endpoints.getUserPosts.matchFulfilled(action)) {
    localStorage.setItem("posts", JSON.stringify(action.payload));
  } else if (Apiservice.endpoints.getTimelinePosts.matchFulfilled(action)) {
    localStorage.setItem("timelineposts", JSON.stringify(action.payload));
  }
  return next(action);
};

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [Apiservice.reducerPath]: Apiservice.reducer,
    user: userReducer,
    post: postReducer,
  },

  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(
      Apiservice.middleware,
      authMiddleware,
      postsMiddleware
    ),
});

export default store;
```

If I provide authMiddleware at the end, the login component is returning nothing for some reason.

This is my userSlice

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import Apiservice from "../service/apiService";

const initialState = {
  userInfo: localStorage.getItem("userInfo")
    ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userInfo"))
    : null,
};

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "userSlice",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addMatcher(
      Apiservice.endpoints.userLogin.matchFulfilled,
      (state, action) => {
        state.userInfo = action.payload;
      }
    );

    builder.addMatcher(
      Apiservice.endpoints.getMyDetails.matchFulfilled,
      (state, action) => {
        state.userInfo = action.payload;
      }
    );
  },
});

export const {} = userSlice.actions;

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

This is the login component where I'm calling the api end point

```
const [userLogin, { isLoading, isError, isSuccess, error, data }] =
    useUserLoginMutation();

  console.log(data);(returns nothing with authMiddleware, but returns the data if removed)

  useEffect(() => {
    // navigate("/");

    if (isSuccess) {
      toast({
        title: "Login Successful.",
        status: "success",
        duration: 5000,
        isClosable: true,
      });
      navigate("/");
    }
    if (isError) {
      toast({
        title: error?.data?.message,
        status: "error",
        duration: 5000,
        isClosable: true,
      });
    }
  }, [isSuccess, toast, navigate, isError, error?.data]);

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    userLogin(data);
  };
```

The login information is being successfully stored in localstorage through the middleware, but when I console.log isSuccess,error,data of the userLogin end point, nothing returns.
Also I've tried console logging the auth middleware, and it's working fine as well. The userLogin endpoint goes through and everything works, but nothing is returned and everything is either undefined or empty. Ofcourse, if I remove the authMiddleware, then everything works fine(I get the data and etc).